# Creating custom rollback method EJB3

Tags: java, jboss, transactions, ejb, jboss6.x

I'm using EJB3.1 in my application which is running on JBoss AS 6. I'm working as integration developer and I have use case where as part of my transaction there are multiple calls to various external systems via REST, SOAP etc. If any of these calls throw exception I have to rollback changes to previously called systems.

Currently I'm having situation:

```
public class SystemAException extends RuntimeException {...}
public class SystemBException extends RuntimeException {...}
public class SystemCException extends RuntimeException {...}
```

System classes

```
public class SystemA{
    public static makeChanges() throws SystemAException{...}
    public static cancelChanges() {...}     
}

public class SystemB{
    public static makeChanges() throws SystemBException{...}
    public static cancelChanges() {...}     
}

public class SystemC{
    public static makeChanges() throws SystemCException{...}
    public static cancelChanges() {...}     
}
```

Call

```
static makeChanges(Object o){
   persist(o); //DB work
   try {
        SystemA.makeChange();
        SystemB.makeChange();
        SystemC.makeChange();
    } catch(SystemBException eb){
        SystemA.cancelChanges();
        throw eb;
    } catch(SystemCException ec){
        SystemA.cancelChanges();
        SystemB.cancelChanges();
        throw ec;
    }
    update(o); //more DB work
}
```

I would like to get rid off try-catch and to instruct JBoss to call method                      `cancelChanges()` whenever RuntimeException occurs like it does when it rollback changes made to DB.

I'm aware that I could use Commander pattern to undo previously made changes, but I would like to know if container can do that for me.

If it is possible, I would like to accomplish following thing

```
static makeChanges(Object o){
   persist(o); //DB work
   SystemA.makeChange();
   SystemB.makeChange();
   SystemC.makeChange();
   update(o); //more DB work
}
```

Comment: I believe you should use something like Spring AOP o AspectJ to intercept the `makeChanges` call using @AfterThrowing, and then implement there the rollback logic. Using normal EJB interceptors I think it's not posible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling non-XA external systems via REST/SOAP, what happens if your JVM/network crashes before you can undo the changes?  That sounds like a fragile architecture.

Regardless, ther is no way to get the EJB container to do this for you automatically.  The best idea I have is to have SystemA/SystemB/SystemC call [TransactionSynchronizationRegistry.registerInterposedSynchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/transaction/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry.html#registerInterposedSynchronization%28javax.transaction.Synchronization%29), and then you can be notified when the transaction is rolling back (since the EJB container will roll back transactions automatically if a system exception or application with rollback=true is thrown), and then you can try to undo whatever.  Of course, if the JVM crashes then your interposed synchronization listeners will be lost and you can't undo, so it still doesn't solve that problem.